# Белый экран после установки arch Linux с KDE

Tags: linux, archlinux, kde

Установил arch Linux с KDE , ребутнул пк , захожу , ввожу пароль и появляется чёрный экран , двигаю мышкой появляется полностью белый экран с серой надписью "No windows" по центру , думал может проблемы с дровами , при установке выбирал nvidia open source , потом All open source , нечего не изменилось , потом попробовал поставить с xfce4 , там все хорошо , в чем может быть проблема и как решить ? Arch ставил через скрипт archinstall видео карта rtx 3050

Comment: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=286024
https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=13803

Answer (score 0):

No windows происходит тогда, когда нету DE, т.е. скорее всего он не видел KDE, попробуйте установить с другого источника, либо использовать другой DE